# Can't connect to database via Ruby and MySQL2

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

When I try to connect to database via Ruby I'm getting this error :

```
conn.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `query=' for #<Mysql2::Client:0x2ee5190> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  query
               _query
```

My code is :

```
require 'mysql2'

connection = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root",:password => "",:database => "ruby")

result = connection.query = ("INSERT INTO datacheck(#{info.keys}) VALUES #{info.values}")
```

Seems that everything is working until this line

```
result = connection.query = ("INSERT INTO datacheck(#{info.keys}) VALUES #{info.values}")
```

I'm looking for someone who can help.

Comment: Shouldn't you call a function without `=` in between?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: it does not exist a `query=` method, but `query` does. Try

```
result = connection.query("INSERT INTO datacheck(#{info.keys}) VALUES #{info.values}")
```